# The entity type 'stream' requires a primary key to be defined. .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I'm Using .NET Core 2.1.1 with Entity Framework Core 2.1.1, and I have the following Entity:

#### Some Entity

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.IO;

namespace MyWebApp.Models
{
    public class Certificate
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime RequestedAt { get; set; }

        public Stream FileStream { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which represents a Certificate object where I plan to store the FileStream of a PDF file, using the last property of course. But When I try either to run a Migration using EF Core's Package Manager console command `Add-Migration Foo`, or when I try to run the project using an in-memory DataBase, I get the following errors:

> #### When trying to add a Role
>
> The entity type 'stream' requires a primary key to be defined.

It only happens when the last property (FileStream) is present in the Entity, if I remove it works fine. I've searched other related questions, and most of them point to either:

- The primary key is not being recognized by EF because of naming conventions.
- A composite Key must be explicitly defined using the Fluent API.
- Just place a `[Key]` attribute before the primary key property.

I've also tried to define the primary key using the Fluent API:

#### Here is my DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.IO;

namespace MyWebbApp.Models
{
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public DbSet<ActionValue> ActionValues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Certificate> Certificates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VisualIVR> VisualIVRs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SMSRequest> SMSRequests { get; set; }

    public DbContext (DbContextOptions<VysContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Certificate>()
            .HasKey(c => c.Id);
    }
}
```

#### Here are the complete exception details

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at VysMiddleware.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory) in H:/MyApp/Startup.cs:line 84

Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Stream' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

It seems to be something regarding the use of the `Stream` type, but I already have a primary key defined. Any suggestions?, Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: EF expects `Stream` to be an entity within the database and is trying to map it to your database. How are you expecting to store a `Stream` in your database? (I feel like I said database too much there).

Comment: If this is about SQL Server's FILESTREAM feature, then sorry, that isn't supported in EF Core. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4573.

Comment: That makes sense, right now I just want to store it in-memory, no persistent Db involved. But in the case where a DB would be used, say SQL Server I would store it in a varbinary column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store a file *stream* in your database currently with EF Core. You have a few options:

- Store the *result* of reading that file stream, which in the case of PDF file would be a `byte[]` blob. It's generally recommended not to store files in the database though.
- Store the *path* to the PDF file in your database. e.g. `"Documents/Certificates/xxxx.pdf"`
- If you don't need the PDF persisted in the database, then just tell EF to ignore it. This can be done by adding a `NotMapped` attribute to the property:

  ```
  public class Certificate
  {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

      public DateTime RequestedAt { get; set; }

      [NotMapped]
      public Stream FileStream { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  or in Fluent API:

  ```
  builder.Entity<Certificate>()
      .HasKey(c => c.Id)
      .Ignore(c => c.FileStream);
  ```